# Calculating Problem when using class in python

Tags: python

```
def main() :
    a = Complex(3.0,-4.5)
    b = Complex(4.0, -5.0)
    c = Complex(-1.0, 0.5)
    print(a+b)
    print(a+b-c)
    print(a-b)
    print(a-b+c)
    print(a-c)
    print(b == (a-c))

class Complex:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def __add__(self, other):
        return Complex(self.x + other.x, self.y + other.y)

    def __sub__(self, other):
        return Complex(self.x - other.x, self.y - other.y)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"Complex({self.x}, {self.y})"

main()
```

I want to get the answer like this:

```
Complex(7.0,-9.5)
Complex(8.0,-10.0)
Complex(-1.0,0.5)
Complex(-2.0,1.0)
Complex(4.0,-5.0)
True
```

Everything is Okay until `Complex(4.0, -5.0)`, but I got '`False`' in the end. So I tried to debug and found  `<__main__.Complex object at 0x0397~~~> == <__main__.Complex object at 0x03E7~~~>` (numbers after 'at' is different) so `False` is shown. I tried to `print(a-c)` and `print(b)` each and they look same when printed but something like address is different.  What should I do to get `True` instead of `False`?

Comment: Your class doesn't implement `__eq__`, or any comparison methods.

Comment: You need to define a [`__eq__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__eq__) method (and probably other comparison dunders too) to override the default object equality check.

Comment: `object at 0x0397` is just the memory adress, so 2 object have different adresses, that's normal. Also read about https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1436703/what-is-the-difference-between-str-and-repr to get a nice readable print for your objects

Comment: You do know that Python has complex numbers built-in, right? e.g. `a = 3+-4.5j`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments you haven't defined the `__eq__` operator which is used for equality comparisons (`==`). Since it's not defined python doesn't know how to compare these two and instead tries comparing their identity like the `is` keyword, which checks if they are the same objects (the address or the "number" after the at is the same).

Here is one implementation of `__eq__`

```
def main() :
    a = Complex(3.0,-4.5)
    b = Complex(4.0, -5.0)
    c = Complex(-1.0, 0.5)
    print(a+b)
    print(a+b-c)
    print(a-b)
    print(a-b+c)
    print(a-c)
    print(b == (a-c))

class Complex:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def __add__(self, other):
        return Complex(self.x + other.x, self.y + other.y)

    def __sub__(self, other):
        return Complex(self.x - other.x, self.y - other.y)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"Complex({self.x}, {self.y})"

    #returns True if the two objects are equal
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.x == other.x and self.y == other.y

main()
```

and you should get `True` as your final output

Comment: Float should never be compared for equality. Use epsilon ball criterion instead. https://floating-point-gui.de/errors/comparison/

Comment: Really thanks! It works but I got small warnings **Implementing __eq__ without also implementing __hash__** does it mean when I use __eq__, I always have to use __hash__?

Answer (score 0):

A quick (but weak) solution would be to change the line

```py
print(b == (a-c))
```

into

```py
print(str(b) == str(a-c))
```

However, if you wanted to implement more foolproof equality checks you should check out the dunder method `__eq__`. For example, you could add the method:

```py
def __eq__(self, other):
    return (self.x, self.y) == (other.x, other.y)
```